# CanCan and preview action - object not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

I defined a preview action as

```
resources :organisations, shallow: true do
  resources :orders do
    get :preview, on: :new
  end
end
```

In my controller I have

```
load_and_authorize_resource :organisation
load_and_authorize_resource :order, through: :organisation, shallow: true
```

My problem is not a matter of permissions, but the @order in the preview action is simply not loaded (it is nil). Is this a problem of the "on: new" not taken care of by CanCan? or is there something else escaping from my attention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diving into the CanCan source code, I found an option "new", that allows to do the following:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :order, through: :organisation, shallow: true, new: :preview
```

After adding this extra option, it "recognizes" the preview action as something similar to "new" and "create", and fills in the @order variable as expected...

Haven't found any documentation about this option though...

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, Cancan will not load your @order (It only takes care of permissions), you need to that inside your controller action.

Comment: Essam - this is not true. Normally Cancan does load the model. That's what load_and_authorize is all about: load and authorize. Even for "member" routes this normally works. So I suspect the "on: :new" to prevent the load from taking place